# how to make row value as column header

Tags: c#, asp.net

i got a problem with grid view ,because I'm new to asp.net(10 days),so i donno how to do it,so  can you guyz please help me out this problem..

i have a simple gridview ,and i have to make new grid with row value as column header name

Empname Earnngs Amount

Austin  HRA   20,000$

Austin  DA  1,000$

Austin  Basic   5,000$

and i have to make like this

.Austin  HRA   DA   BASIC

```
    2000$ 2000$ 2000$
```

Please give some idea and some examples using C# to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of doing this using an asp GridView:

```
// Create new DataTable.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// Total count of columns.
int colCount = 3;

// Add 3 columns.
for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col" + i.ToString()));
}

// Add data to the datatable.
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Empname", "Earnngs", "Amount" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Austin", "Earnngs", "Amount" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Austin", "df", "Amount" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "sdfsdf", "dsfdf", "df" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Empdsfsdfname", "Earnngs", "df" });

// Loop through each column in the DataTable and set the column name to the data in the first row of data.
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    dc.ColumnName = dt.Rows[0][dc].ToString();
}

// Set the datasource of the grid.
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;

// Bind the data to the grid.
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

See these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=VS.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx

Comment: i will try and let you know,anyways thanx for for quick response

Comment: thank you for your quick response and effort..but this is not working,this like static thing,i have to make in dynamic way..like row name should be come from the database..than it should add as columns name,because user has permission to add many earnings to the database  ....waiting for your reply

Comment: So create a SqlCommand, run a query, get a result set, loop through it, and create your column names, and your data. Your question did not ask this.

Comment: See the example at the bottom here, which will show how to create a SqlDataReader and loop through it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer if it answered the initially asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. However create DataTable with first row values as dataColumn name and rest data will go as data row. Bind this table to the grid.

Comment: ,i will try out and let you know..anyways one example will help more,and many thanx for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

if any one face this kind of problem you can refer this coding

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your query", con);
            SqlDataReader rdr;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();


            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();


            rdr.Read();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rdr[Index].ToString()));
            rdr.Close();

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rdr[Index].ToString()));
            }

            rdr.Close();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string Amount = rdr[Index].ToString();
                string EarnName = rdr[Index].ToString();
                newRow[EarnName] = Amount;


            }
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

[DownLoad Torrent at High Speed](http://www.hackme.co.vu)